# PHP attribute of array value

Tags: php, arrays

Apologies if this has been asked before but I dont know what the process is called so I dont know how to search for it...

I want to print out the name of the top scorer in an exam. I have built an array that returns the top score:

```
$tom = 90;
$dick = 80;
$harry = 70;

$n = array($tom, $dick, $harry);
arsort($n);
$keys = array_keys($n);

$top_score_1 = $n[$keys[0]];

echo $top_score_1; //prints 90
```

However I want it to print the name 'Tom' instead the score. How can I add each persons name to their score so that

```
echo $top_score_1; //prints Tom
```

Many thanks for any help,

P

Comment: You could make a multidimensional array, e.g. `$arr = [["score" => 12, "name" = "xy"]...];`

Comment: *slightly* harder to sort multi dimensional arrays if you don't actually need the extra dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i restructured the array - hope that's ok

```
<?php
$tom = 90;
$dick = 80;
$harry = 70;

$n = array('tom'=>$tom, 'dick'=>$dick, 'harry'=>$harry);
arsort($n);

$first_key = key($n); //key returns the current key, which will just be the first key in this case

echo $first_key; //tom
```